# GitHub Mylyn connector: Getting issues from GitHub

Tags: github, mylyn

I'm using this GitHub Mylyn connector: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/github-mylyn-connector

However, when someone is creating an issue on GitHub itself, it doesn't get updated in my tasks in Eclipse.
I am working in a team, therefore want to have the possibility to share all the tasks. The idea behind Mylyn was to create tasks, sync it with GitHub and everyone else will just sync their task list against the issue list on GitHub.
As I mentioned, somehow it doesn't sync any tasks that were created on GitHub itself, therefore I assume that tasks I create in Mylyn and sync with GitHub won't be synced to my colleagues computer as well.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have set the right query, as mentioned in http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/GitHub/UserGuide ?

Comment: Wow. That worked. You wanna submit an answer? Maybe elaborate a little about the queries, for further references.

Comment: Answer posted, with a reference to the exact subset of GitHub API used by Egit/Mylyn.

Comment: I'm sorry but I find that user guide unhelpful.  I am seeing some of my github issues listed in Mylyn's task list, but not all. And so I added a New Query called it All Issues and restricted it to nothing. But I'm bamboozled by this UI. I can see no way to edit that query, Ic an see nowhere where it's recorded or I can view it, and I only see a means for adding another new query,. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: But, I think I stumbled upon the answer. Been a bit time consuming and the documentation could have been better. But when you create a New Query, it appears on the MyLyn task list ... oddly that view is categorized and in spite of a toolbar button that has a tooltip saying Categorized, it does nothing when clicked so I can't toggle it from a categorized view to uncategorized, but the new query appears as a category. Further I do see all my gitub issues there and I can right click them all assign them another working category in which case they appear under that category and the query!

Comment: So methinks I've worked it out though MyLyn task list behaviour seems a tad unusual and the documentation could be clearer as to what a Query is and where we can see the results of a Query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea behind the link between GitHub issue and Mylyn is to define a **[query](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/GitHub/UserGuide#Queries)**:

[image: GitHub issue Mylyn query]

> GitHub issue task repositories support creating queries that filter by the following fields:
>
> - State (open or closed)
> - Milestones
> - Mentions
> - Assignee
> - Labels

So if you don't define a query for the issues (especially for the ones assigned to *you* or your team), you won't see them.

That query will use the [GitHub v3 API for issues](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/).
([Huboard](http://huboard.com/) is an example of another service, beside Egit, which uses that API: as described in [Huboard – Github issues made awesome](http://lostechies.com/ryanrauh/2012/01/13/huboard-github-issues-made-awesome/), by [Ryan Rauh](http://lostechies.com/ryanrauh/author/ryanrauh/))

Comment: Unfortunately I find the linked to document and this explanation a little incomplete as I can't understand from it, how to add queries (which I did divine by exploring the menus and I found it on the Mylyn Task Repositories view when right-clicking a Github task repository I see a `New Query...` menu item), how to modify them, see them, diagnose them, etc. I see no useful interface to queries in exploring menus and no clues in the documentation linked to nor in this answer. It remains a little nebulous. Is there any chance of clarifying things?

Comment: @BerndWechner Clarifying things 7+ years later? I'll have to check, I haven't used Mylyn recently.

Comment: @BerndWechner I don't find many *recent* resources. I only have https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn, which has been updated in 2018.

Comment: Yeah, well the problem continues to exist, 7 years later, and the beauty of stack overflow and web search engines is that issues and their solutions or efforts at them remain findable by suckers experiencing the same problem even 7 years later ;-)

Alas the link you found there relates to redmine not the github connector, and I can't see the relationship. I'm researching myself as well, and I guess you don't need to do it for me, the question was only there in case you have expertise that brings us to an understanding which research so far, hasn't.