# Why Mylyn is not getting issues from GitHub?

Tags: eclipse, github, issue-tracking, mylyn

I recently started to use GitHub Mylyn connector for Eclipse and I have it working, I create new tasks and I can see them in Eclipse and GitHub.

The problem is when me or someone else create an Issue on GitHub I can't see it on Eclipse. I have done [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175919/github-mylyn-connector-getting-issues-from-github) and configured Mylyn on that way as you can see in the image:

[image]

But as you can see under "Bugs and Enhancements" I have nothing and [here](https://github.com/dragondgold/MultiWork/issues?milestone=none&state=open#keyboard_shortcuts_pane) I actually have one issues, so, why don't they appear? Is something to do with the fields `Assigned to` and `Mentioning` ? I have filled both with my GitHub username, then only one but with no results.

Comment: What version of Eclipse and of EGit are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno, Egit v2.3.1 and Eclipse Mylyn to GitHub connector v2.3.0

Answer (score 3):

I was also having same problem. The problem here is that the `Labels` which are checked have `And` relationship rather than `Or` relationship, i.e if you check both `bug` and `enhancement` only the tasks that are labelled both bug and enhancements will show up there.

So, I think it will work if create separate query for enhancements and bugs.

Comment: +1 it was the same issue, tnx mate. Unchecking every label returns every issue.